# Make mysqldump output USE statements or full table names when dumping a single table with where clause

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to get mysqldump to output USE statements for a single (partial) table dump?

I've already got some scripts that I'd like to reuse which run mysqldump with some arguments and apply them to a remote server.

However, since I haven't bothered to parse all the arguments to mysqldump, and there is no `USE` in the dump, the remote server is saying no database selected.

I'm a programmer more than anything else, so I can easily use sed to modify the dump before applying it in the worst case, but those scripts won't allow me to do this as I don't have access to the dump between creation and application.

**EDIT:** the ability to output fully qualified table names may also solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump` can be cajoled into performing as requested by combining the `--databases` (force USE statements on databases) and `--tables` (force following arguments to be evaluated as tables) flags:

`mysqldump -B dbname --tables tablename`